# Where do I store reports created by my application on OSX

Tags: macos

My application stores logs in /Users/*username*/Library/Logs/*appname* and preferences in /Users/*username*/Library/Preferences/*appname* but where I should store the reports it creates.

Originally they were in Logs, but they are not really logs. I then thought about putting them in /Users/*username*/Library/Reports/*appname* but the Reports folder does not exist under Library and it seems bad practise to create additional folders at this level.

What is the correct mac-friendly way to do things ?

Comment: Do only open your reports in your app or in other apps?

Comment: The reports are html and so canbe opened in any webbrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I figured, those are reports that are the end result of the app itself and are something the user needs to have access to.
Even more so, the reports are HTML (so a valid recognizable format)?

I think that constitutes them as documents.
I would put a folder in documents named after the app and put the reports there.
A lot of apps do that (Office comes to mind at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

A good candidate would be your app's folder in ~/Library/Application Support/

You may need to create it, and you should really use the bundle identifier for your app as the folder name. 
~/Library/Application Support/com.bundleIdentifier.something/

In there you can create whatever you need to to support your app.

[File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW15)

> Important: The files in the user’s Documents and Desktop directories
>   should reflect only the documents that the user created and works with
>   directly. Similarly, the media directories should contain only the
>   user’s media files. Those directories must never be used to store data
>   files that your app creates and manages automatically. If you need a
>   place to store automatically generated files, use the Library
>   directory, which is designated specifically for that purpose. For
>   information on where to put files in the Library directory, see “The
>   Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files.”
>
> **Application Support** Use this directory to store all app data files except those associated with the user’s documents. For example, you
>   might use this directory to store app-created data files,
>   configuration files, templates, or other fixed or modifiable resources
>   that are managed by the app. An app might use this directory to store
>   a modifiable copy of resources contained initially in the app’s
>   bundle. A game might use this directory to store new levels purchased
>   by the user and downloaded from a server. All content in this
>   directory should be placed in a custom subdirectory whose name is that
>   of your app’s bundle identifier or your company. In iOS, the contents
>   of this directory are backed up by iTunes.

Comment: I assumed (maybe wrongly) that ApplicationSupport was for files needed to run the application, whereas these reports are created by the application to help the user. Thx for the tip about bundleidentifier although looking at my mac not many applications seem to do that anymore.

Comment: Application Support is not for data the user or oter apps can use.

Comment: Hmm. From the File System Programming Guide:

Comment: Hmm, none of the examples given are like my reports files so I have to say remain unconvinced.

Comment: Well then you'll need to figure it out on your own. Either you want people to access and edit these directly often, or rarely. If you're going to go with ~/Documents then you should just let the user choose the location. If your app depends on this stuff going to a reliable location, you'd better choose the location and not put it in a place like documents, or you end up needing to handle people moving it around all the time.